# How to show a progress Dialog before data loading in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, progress-bar, loading, dataloader

In my Flutter project, I am doing API calls to fetch data by GET request. After parsing the **JSON object** from the response, I just show the value in the **Text** widget. While the data takes time to load, in the meantime my Text widgets show null.

For the API calling section I have the following code-

```
class Webservice {
  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    var jwt = await LocalStore().getJWT();
    print(jwt);

    final response = await http.get(resource.url,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'token': '${Constants.TOKEN}',
          'jwt': '$jwt',
        }
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('${response.body}');
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
```

I made a **Model class** for JSON parsing-

```
class Category {
  int catNote;
  int catTodo;
  int catRem;
  int catTag;
  int catUrgent;
  int catWork;
  int catOffice;
  int catPersonal;
  
  Category(
      {this.catNote,
        this.catTodo,
        this.catRem,
        this.catTag,
        this.catUrgent,
        this.catWork,
        this.catOffice,
        this.catPersonal});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    catNote = json['cat_note'];
    catTodo = json['cat_todo'];
    catRem = json['cat_rem'];
    catTag = json['cat_tag'];
    catUrgent = json['cat_urgent'];
    catWork = json['cat_work'];
    catOffice = json['cat_office'];
    catPersonal = json['cat_personal'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['cat_note'] = this.catNote;
    data['cat_todo'] = this.catTodo;
    data['cat_rem'] = this.catRem;
    data['cat_tag'] = this.catTag;
    data['cat_urgent'] = this.catUrgent;
    data['cat_work'] = this.catWork;
    data['cat_office'] = this.catOffice;
    data['cat_personal'] = this.catPersonal;
    return data;
  }

  static Resource<Category> get allCategory {
    return Resource(
        url: '${Constants.BASE_URL}category',
        parse: (response) {
          print('my result ${response.body}');
          final result = json.decode(response.body);

          Category category = Category.fromJson(result) ;
          return category;

        }
    );

  }

}
```

Now, in my main class, I have created one function like below-

```
  void _getAllCategories() {
    Webservice().load(Category.allCategory).then((newsArticles) => {
        setState(() => {
      _category = newsArticles
    })
  });
 }
```

After that, I have called the function inside the initState function and saved the value in the _category object.

Then inside the  **Widget build(BuildContext context)** function for Text widget I have used the value from **_category** object like below using a ternary operator to check whether the object is null or not. If it's null then it should show 0 and if it is not null then should show the original value-

```
child: _category ==null?
                Text('0',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
                ):
                Text('${_category.catToDo}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                )
```

But it is still showing null whiling taking few second for data loading and shows output like below-

[image]

So, I need a solution to show a progress dialog or just show the default value as 0 while the data takes time to load. It would be very nice if someone helps me out with this code.

Comment: Future.builder class - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: same issue i am facing while fetching data in text field from api

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a FutureBuilder to control the rendering during the load time;

```
  final categories = Webservice().load(Category.allCategory);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: categories,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        var value = (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) ? '${_category.catToDo}' : '0';

        return Text(
          value,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Or if you want to display a loading animation :

```
  final categories = Webservice().load(Category.allCategory);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: categories,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Text(
            '${_category.catToDo}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          );
        }
        else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) package to show a loading spin with different styles.

After that you need to use [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget

Here is an example of how to use it with the spinkit

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: myAwesomeFutureMethod(), // you should put here your method that call your web service
        builder:

            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<BillResponse>> snapshot) { 
            /// The snapshot data type have to be same of the result of your web service method
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            /// When the result of the future call respond and has data show that data
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: bodyData(snapshot.data),
            );
          }
          /// While is no data show this
          return Center(
            child: SpinKitDualRing(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Hope this could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `_category` is null, maybe you're assigning a value to it before loading the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the Cellular bar progress indicator, the following is the demo for it:

[image]

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            BarProgressIndicator(
              numberOfBars: 4,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 5.0,
              barSpacing: 2.0,
              beginTweenValue: 5.0,
              endTweenValue: 13.0,
              milliseconds: 200,
            ),
            Text(
              'Cellular bar progress indicator',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  final int numberOfBars;
  final double fontSize;
  final double barSpacing;
  final Color color;
  final int milliseconds;
  final double beginTweenValue;
  final double endTweenValue;

  BarProgressIndicator({
    this.numberOfBars = 3,
    this.fontSize = 10.0,
    this.color = Colors.black,
    this.barSpacing = 0.0,
    this.milliseconds = 250,
    this.beginTweenValue = 5.0,
    this.endTweenValue = 10.0,
  });

  _BarProgressIndicatorState createState() => _BarProgressIndicatorState(
        numberOfBars: this.numberOfBars,
        fontSize: this.fontSize,
        color: this.color,
        barSpacing: this.barSpacing,
        milliseconds: this.milliseconds,
        beginTweenValue: this.beginTweenValue,
        endTweenValue: this.endTweenValue,
      );
}

class _BarProgressIndicatorState extends State<BarProgressIndicator>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int numberOfBars;
  int milliseconds;
  double fontSize;
  double barSpacing;
  Color color;
  double beginTweenValue;
  double endTweenValue;
  List<AnimationController> controllers = new List<AnimationController>();
  List<Animation<double>> animations = new List<Animation<double>>();
  List<Widget> _widgets = new List<Widget>();

  _BarProgressIndicatorState({
    this.numberOfBars,
    this.fontSize,
    this.color,
    this.barSpacing,
    this.milliseconds,
    this.beginTweenValue,
    this.endTweenValue,
  });

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
      _addAnimationControllers();
      _buildAnimations(i);
      _addListOfDots(i);
    }

    controllers[0].forward();
  }

  void _addAnimationControllers() {
    controllers.add(AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), vsync: this));
  }

  void _addListOfDots(int index) {
    _widgets.add(Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: barSpacing),
      child: _AnimatingBar(
        animation: animations[index],
        fontSize: fontSize,
        color: color,
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _buildAnimations(int index) {
    animations.add(
        Tween(begin: widget.beginTweenValue, end: widget.endTweenValue)
            .animate(controllers[index])
              ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
                if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
                  controllers[index].reverse();
                if (index == numberOfBars - 1 &&
                    status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
                  controllers[0].forward();
                }
                if (animations[index].value > widget.endTweenValue / 2 &&
                    index < numberOfBars - 1) {
                  controllers[index + 1].forward();
                }
              }));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 30.0,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: _widgets,
      ),
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) controllers[i].dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class _AnimatingBar extends AnimatedWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double fontSize;
  _AnimatingBar(
      {Key key, Animation<double> animation, this.color, this.fontSize})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation = listenable;
    return Container(
      height: animation.value,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        border: Border.all(color: color),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
        color: color,
      ),
      width: fontSize,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without using Futurebuilder**

before API call, Like

```
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  content: Row(children: [
    CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7), child: Text("Loading...")),
  ]),
);
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return alert;
  },
);
getAllCategories()      //API call
```

After getting API response

```
var response = getAllCategories()       //API call
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Note : You can put the code into a method and then call it here